# Jackson & JSONAnySetter: NullPointer Exception during Serialization/Deserialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have a problem with serialization/deserialization with Jackson 1.9.13 (and Jackson 2.5.0) and fighting this now for a few days without any success.

My goal is to use @JsonAnyGetter & @JsonAnySetter, and I want to calculate dynamically if a object should be written to the output or not. I have a JSON definition which I serialize with the ObjectMapper (and check if the Object should be included or not), and then I convert the object back to a string.

I am using a "HidableSerializer" for this, which works fine during serialization, but not when converting the object back to a string.

Without @JsonAnySetter / -getter **or** the "HidableSerializer", everythings works fine, but not both together.

Why is this not working? And how can I solve the problem? Better approaches are welcome!

The stack trace looks like this:

**Stack Trace**

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: ch.hasselba.Test["[anySetter]"])
null
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:218)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:183)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.SerializerBase.wrapAndThrow(SerializerBase.java:140)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:158)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
at ch.hasselba.HidableSerializer.serialize(HidableSerializer.java:29)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:610)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:256)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2575)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2097)
    at ch.hasselba.Demo.main(Demo.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:243)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.AnyGetterWriter.getAndSerialize(AnyGetterWriter.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
```

**The Demo code**

```
package ch.hasselba;

import org.codehaus.jackson.Version;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicBeanDescription;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.module.SimpleModule;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerModifier;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // register the module
        Version version = new Version(1, 0, 0, "SNAPSHOT");
        mapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule("HidableModule", version) {
            @Override
            public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
                super.setupModule(context);
                context.addBeanSerializerModifier(new BeanSerializerModifier() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    @Override
                    public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config, BasicBeanDescription desc,
                        JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {
                        if (IHidable.class.isAssignableFrom(desc.getBeanClass())) {
                            return new HidableSerializer<Object>((JsonSerializer<Object>) serializer);
                        }
                        return serializer;
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // the data
        String content = "{ \"foo\": \"bar\" }";

        // build the Object
        Test test = null;
        try {
            test =  mapper.readValue(content, Test.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // and now convert it back to a String
        String data = null;
        try {
             data = mapper.writeValueAsString(test);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println( data );

    }

}
```

**Test class**

```
package ch.hasselba;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAnyGetter;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAnySetter;

public class Test implements IHidable {

    private Map<String, Object> others = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getOthers() {
        return this.others;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void addOther(final String name, final Object value) {   
        this.others.put(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isHidden() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

**The Hidable Serializer**

```
package ch.hasselba;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializerProvider;

public class HidableSerializer<T> extends JsonSerializer<T> {

    private JsonSerializer<T> defaultSerializer;

    public HidableSerializer(JsonSerializer<T> serializer) {
        defaultSerializer = serializer;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(T value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        if( value instanceof IHidable ){
            IHidable hidableValue = (IHidable) value;
            if( hidableValue.isHidden() )
                return;
        }
        defaultSerializer.serialize(value, jgen, provider);

    }

}
```

**IHidableInterface**

```
package ch.hasselba;


public interface IHidable {
    boolean isHidden();
}
```

Comment: I have tested it with Jackson 2.5.0, same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the *defaultSerializer* instance, you are using inside your *HidableSerializer*, is a [ResolvableSerializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/ResolvableSerializer.html) (BeanSerializer), but as you wrap it into *JsonSerializer* (HidableSerializer) in your *modifySerializer()* method, it's *resolve()* method is then never invoked and it fails to initialize properly.

If you try adding the following line to your *HidableSerializer.serialize()* method:

```
...
((ResolvableSerializer)defaultSerializer).resolve(provider);
defaultSerializer.serialize(value, jgen, provider);
...
```

it should do the trick.

If this works for you, a more permanent solution would be to make your *HidableSerializer* implement *ResolvableSerializer* itself and just delegate *resolve()* to the *defaultSerializer*, like this:

```
@Override
public void resolve(SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws JsonMappingException {
    if(defaultSerializer instanceof ResolvableSerializer) {
         ((ResolvableSerializer)defaultSerializer).resolve(serializerProvider);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I went through debugging process and found some [code](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/SerializerCache.java):

```
if (ser instanceof ResolvableSerializer) {
    ((ResolvableSerializer) ser).resolve(provider);
}
```

It actually instantiates key serializer which throws NPE in your case.

Modify your HidableSerializer and it will do the trick:

```
public class HidableSerializer<T> extends JsonSerializer<T> implements ResolvableSerializer {

    private JsonSerializer<T> defaultSerializer;

    public HidableSerializer(JsonSerializer<T> serializer) {
        defaultSerializer = serializer;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(T value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        if( value instanceof IHidable ){
            IHidable hidableValue = (IHidable) value;
            if( hidableValue.isHidden() )
                return;
        }
        defaultSerializer.serialize(value, jgen, provider);

    }

    @Override
    public void resolve(SerializerProvider provider) throws JsonMappingException {
        ((ResolvableSerializer)defaultSerializer).resolve(provider);
    }
}
```

Comment: I came to exactly the same conclusion, just half an hour earlier (see my answer below) :)

Comment: Thanks, but as @zeppelin wrote, his solution came up a little bit earlier.